# Facebook share content is working in my simulator but not on my device

Tags: facebook, swift3, ios-simulator, share

Hi I am new to swift 3 and Xcode 8 I have an issue with that my facebook share option with initial text content is working fine in my simulator which shows facebook post pop-up with content but not showing contents on my device in facebook post pop-up

```
import UIKit
import Social
import FBSDKLoginKit
import CoreData
class ViewControllerGame: UIViewController {
var seconds = 30
var timer = Timer()
var cur = 0;
var d = 0;
       var someValue: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        scoreLabel.text = "\(someValue)"
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var tapHere: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func logoutButton(_ sender: Any) {


    FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
   }

@IBAction func highScoreBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    highscore()
   }
func highscoreAlertView(title:String, message:String){

let highscorealert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    highscorealert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
        highscorealert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))
    self.present(highscorealert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
     @IBAction func tapHere(_ sender: UIButton) {
         someValue += 1
     d = self.someValue
    }

   @IBOutlet weak var sliderOutlet: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var startOutlet: UIButton!
@IBAction func start(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewControllerGame.counter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    startOutlet.isHidden = true
    tapHere.isHidden = false
    scoreLabel.isHidden = false
}
func highscore(){

    let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate) as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let score = ScoreList(context:context)

    score.newScore = Int32(self.someValue)
    appDelegate.saveContext()
    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(ScoreList.fetchRequest())

        let scores = result as! [ScoreList]

        for score in scores {
            print("Scores: \(score.newScore)")
        }
        let f = scores.sorted(by: {$0.newScore > $1.newScore })
        print("Here:\(f)")

      /*  if let scoreArray = f as? NSDictionary{

         let scoreArr=(scoreArray["newScore"] as? Int32)
        print("asdf:\(scoreArr!)")
        }
        else{
        print("asdasdfsdf")

        }

 */

    } catch {
        print("Error")
    }
     highscoreAlertView(title: "HIGHSCORES", message:"")




}
 func counter()
{
    if(self.seconds != 0){
        seconds -= 1
        label.text = String(format: "%02d", self.seconds % 60 )
    }
     if (seconds == 0)
    {
        timer.invalidate()
        self.label.text = "00"
        createAlert(title: "Your Score is", message: "\(self.someValue)")
                  self.seconds = 30

    }
}
  @IBAction func shareButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let shareToFacebook : SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
    shareToFacebook.setInitialText("Timer Game score is \(d)")
    self.present(shareToFacebook, animated: true, completion: nil)
self.commonthing()
 }
  func createAlert (title:String, message:String)
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "RETRY", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
          self.commonthing()
      }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "SHARE", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
         let shareToFacebook : SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        shareToFacebook.setInitialText("Timer Game score is \(self.d)")
        self.present(shareToFacebook, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.commonthing()

    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func commonthing(){
    self.seconds = 30
    self.label.text = "30"
    self.viewDidLoad()
 }
       override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    someValue = 0
    self.seconds = 30
    tapHere.isHidden = true
    scoreLabel.isHidden = true
    startOutlet.isHidden = false
 }
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```